# How can I prove that the inverse function of a total recursive function is recursive?

Tags: functions, logic, first-order-logic, recursion

The full question actually is :

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a function.
Prove that if $f$ is a total recursive function and $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ recursive, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is recursive.

I guess that the part that $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is recursive is helping us to understand that this statement is true. However, I do not know how to prove it.

Any help would be very much appreciated it.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a recursive function and a recursive set of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: the question is not to show that the inverse *function* is recursive, but rather to show that the *set* $f^{-1}(A) = \{ n \in \mathbb{N}| f(n) \in A \}$ is recursive.

Now, given that $A$ is recursive, we know that its characteristic function $c_A$ is recursive, where $c_A(n)=1$ if $n \in A$ and $c_A(n)=0$ if $n \not \in A$

And since $f$ is recursive, the composition $c_A(f)$ is recursive as well, where we have $c_A(f(n))=1$ if $f(n) \in A$ and $c_A(f(n))=0$ if $f(n) \not \in A$. But that is exactly the characteristic function of $f^{-1}(A)$. Hence, the set $f^{-1}(A)$ is recursive.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense.  I assumed "$f^{-1}(A)$ is recursive" meant $f^{-1}$ is recursive over the domain of $A$", instead of "the image of $f^{-1}$ for the domain $A$ is a recursive set".  Was wondering wny $A$ was specified to be recursive but your interpretation makes more sense.  Also, short answer, $$\lambda a.\mu y.(fy = a)$$

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you so much.

Comment: @MariaMrf You're welcome! :)